# Oracle forms sort records

Tags: oracle, sorting, oracle11g, oracleforms

What I wanted is to sort records in a multi-record block before saving like this:

[image]

I already tried to change the order by of this item in here:

[image]

But it has no effect(I think).

I also want to know if I can automatically sort records in 
***WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE*** in block level so that after entering the last record, it will be sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to have a multi-record *block* ( `block1` ) with *Query Data Source Name* property set to a *table name* which has a varchar2 type column namely `str1`,

and a *Text Item* (`str1`) with *Database Item* Property is "Yes" ( i.e. default ),

and lastly have a *button* with the following code inside of *WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED* trigger of it :

```
declare
   v_blk varchar2(25) := 'block1';
begin   
   commit_form;    
   go_block(v_blk);
   execute_query;
end;
```

Provided we set *ORDER BY Clause* property set to `ascii(str1)` as in the picture below, we'll be able to get the desired output when the button pressed after letters are entered in the order of 'h','e','l','l','o'.

[image]